# Customer Address create order

Tags: orders, adminhtml, customer, address

when you create an order for a customer via the adminhtml you can select from a list of addresses. I am trying to find where in the code i can override or use an observer to modify the list of addresses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addresses come from this method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Address::getAddressCollection()`.
If you want to change this behavior you will have to copy the file in the `local` folder and do your edits there. because this block is not instantiated when you view the order form. Only it's children `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Billing_Address` and `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Shipping_Address` are instantiated.
If you plan to have a different logic for billing and shipping addresses you can rewrite each one of the blocks mentioned above.
If you want the same logic for both, do what I mentioned before. Copy `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Address` in `local` and do your magic there.

Comment: okay thanks. which is safer from the point of view of conflicting with other extensions?

Comment: I think it would be safer to rewrite each class (Billing and shipping) but if you have the same logic for both you will get duplicate code.

Comment: is there a way to do this via observers?

Comment: @Conrad. Not that I know of, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I ran "# grep -r dispatchEvent * | grep address" and couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I think i'm going to actually override the Mage_Customer_Model_Customer add handle it there.